# How can I pass data into a class in python?

Tags: python

I am using django to create a blog editing page. However, my struggles do not involve django, rather just python. I have a class:

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, initcontent):
    self.initcontent = initcontent
title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Post Title')
short_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":3, "cols":100}))
content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget(), initial=Post.objects.get(pk=initcontent).content)
```

and I am initialising it like this:

```
form = EditForm()
form.initcontent = post.pk
```

however I get the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Rayyan Admin\Documents\GitHub\shaista-s-cooking-blog\blogger\forms.py", line 34, in EditForm
content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget(), initial=Post.objects.get(pk=initcontent).content)
NameError: name 'initcontent' is not defined
```

How do i pass initcontent into the class?

Comment: Note the indentation, the `__init__` function does not belong to the class `EditForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your indenting is off so I'm not sure if that's a mistake in formatting here or causing issues with your code.

Anyways I think what you want is:

```
class EditForm():

    def __init__(self, initcontent):
        self.initcontent = initcontent

form = EditForm(post.pk)
```

Comment: yea sorry, the indentation went weird on stack overflow, its fine in my ide, but im still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make an instance of a class, you can pass your data into it if you have defined a constructor. That is the role of a constructor. In your case, you have defined a constructor with initcontent as a parameter. So you can do it like this -

```
form = EditForm(whatever you need to pass)
```

This will do.

Comment: I did as you said but i still get NameError: name 'initcontent' is not defined

Comment: It's because you have not defined initcontent outside your constructor, so you cannot pass pk = initcontent.

Comment: And where are you making that form object ??

Comment: Form class is in a file called forms.py, and object is made in another file called views.py. How should I be defining initcontent then?

Comment: Make the form object in the forms.py file then you can access form.initcontent inside that file.